# Content files are not deployed in the Service Fabric package for asp.net core

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've an asp.net core project with appsettings.json file being copied to the output directory on each build with following "copyToOutput" option in project.json file. When I build it and go to the build folder I can see it. But when I build a Service Fabric application that uses this asp.net core project as service, in package folder, appsettings.json file is missing. Are there any issues with processing content files for asp.net core?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem was related to the fact that there is being called `dotnet publish` step when creating ASF package. Hence "copyToOutput" was supposed to be done via "publishOptions".